# If all proposition are dependent, is the truth value of the AND gate dependent as well?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have been thinking about a question. Let us take an AND gate. In this AND gate, every proposition is dependent on another proposition. Given that there is no circular dependence, I can understand that if the number of propositions is finite, then the truth value of the AND gate is dependent on a proposition outside of the AND gate. Does this hold true for an AND gate with infinite propositions as well?

Comment: An AND gate has two boolean inputs and one boolean output. What do you mean by propositions "inside" and "outside" the gate?

Comment: By AND, I just mean conjunction (inputs could be more than 2 but all have to be true for the conjunction to be true). My question is this, which I think I was unable to phrase correctly: A dependent proposition is that which depends/is grounded by another proposition. Now, given that there is no circular dependence in these propositions, and we have a finite number of propositions in the conjunction, the conjunction (its truth value) would depend on another proposition. But does this stand for infinite number of propositions as well?

Comment: I'd say that the truth value of a conjunction depends on the truth values of its sub-propositions, by definition. Do you mean something else by "depends"?

Comment: Maybe you're wondering whether there can exist an "infinitely deep" logic diagram that has no external inputs. We could certainly define such an object, but it wouldn't be directly relevant to propositional logic. Propositional formulas are defined inductively starting with atomic propositions, so they can't extend infinitely downward.

Comment: The *output* is "dependent on" (it is uniquely determined) by the *inputs*; see [Truth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_function).

Comment: @Karl I am talking about an infinitely long gate diagram. Would it not be just connectors/gates without input in it?

Comment: Yes, we can conceive of such a thing and model it as a mathematical object. But what will you do with it? It doesn't correspond to a propositional function.